# System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged not working with vbscript(system without .net 3.5, but .net 4.5 is present)

Tags: c#, encryption, vbscript, .net-4.5

I am using `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged` in VBScript to encrypt some data. I am getting an error which says, that it needs .net framework 3.5. System does not have .net 3.5, but .net 4.5 is present on the machine.

Also, C# code is able to use the same library (`System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`) for encrypting/decrypting the data in the same environment (without .net 3.5, with .net 4.5).

Below is the code snippet from VBScript:

```vb
Set obj=CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged")
Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")

obj.GenerateKey()
obj.GenerateIV()
```

I have installed .net 3.5 and tested, it works fine. However, I need to run it even if .net 3.5 is not there on the system. For my application, only .net 4.5 is a requirement.